# Multiple hyperlinks in a single cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to use `HYPERLINK` to add multiple links to a cell, like this:

```
="Click "&HYPERLINK("google.com","here")&" or "&HYPERLINK("bing.com","here")&"."
```

But the above code merely results in plain text with no links at all.  Per [this Google support post from 2019](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10846662?hl=en), this doesn't seem to be a feature of Google Sheets but I'm curious whether anyone has come up with a way to accomplish this or some kind of workaround since then.